# Sending a POST request from STORE

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs4, extjs, extjs-mvc, extjs4.1

This is my Store class. I am trying to get a POST request done. Here's my code;
Everything works fine, i also get the Server response when i check it from Firebug. But the only problem is that when i check the `Params tab` in firefox i see `_dc    1341141752113` , and when i check the `Post tab` in firebug i see

```
limit   25
page    1
start   0
```

1.) These are some pamaters which i didnt pass in my code. Why am i getting these ?

```
Ext.define('Pro.store.Animal',{
    extend:'Ext.data.Store',
    model:'Pro.model.Animal',

    proxy: {
        actionMethods : {

            read   : 'POST'
        },
        type: 'ajax',
        url : '/projectmy/animal.php'

    }

    });
```

2.) If i want to pass parameters to a PHP file, how should i edit my code to pass the parameters ?

Comment: Could you get any information about your 2.)? I'm having the same problem. I can't pass any parameters to the PHP script.

Comment: Look at my answer below, i have added the code for the Store. It should help you. (I'm assuming that you have no problems with your PHP script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Ext.define('App.store.StoreName', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    requires: [
        'App.model.StoreName'
    ],

    constructor: function(cfg) {
        var me = this;
        cfg = cfg || {};
        me.callParent([Ext.apply({
            storeId: 'stid',
            model: 'App.model.MyModel',
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                actionMethods: 'POST',
                api: {
                    read: '../myreadPhp.php',

                },
                reader: {
                    type: 'json'
                }
            },
            listeners: {
                beforeload: {
                    fn: me.onArraystoreBeforeLoad,
                    scope: me
                }
            }
        }, cfg)]);
    },

    onArraystoreBeforeLoad: function(store, operation, options) {
        this.proxy.extraParams.yournameparameter = "pass some name here"; 
        this.proxy.extraParams.yourageparamete = "pass your age here"; 
    }

});
```

`myreadPhp.php` will be expecting the parameter `yournameparameter`  and `yourageparamete`

Answer (score 5):

These parameters are defaults. They will be needed if you use an pagination-toolbar or other controls to navigate through your data.
For additional parameter you can use [extraParams in your proxy](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax-cfg-extraParams).

Comment: Adding on to this answer, the _dc is the "cache-busting" parameter that is added automatically to ensure a unique url is called each time.  See the noCache parameter in the Ext.data.proxy.Server class.